# jQuery Clear Appended Textbox

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here's the code:

```
function newRow(){
    var sourceRow = $('table#listings tr.row').html();
    $('table#listings > tbody:last').append('<tr>'+sourceRow+'</tr>');
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id='listings'>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' name='entry[]' value='ENTRY1' />
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The code works but how will i automatically clear the newly appended row textbox? Because it copies whatever the previous row has. I tried:

```
var sourceRow = $('table#listings tr.row').html();
var x = $(sourceRow).('input').children().val(''); //problematic line
$('table#listings > tbody:last').append('<tr>'+sourceRow+'</tr>');
return false;
```

but didn't work.

I want to have an ouput:

```
<table id='listings'>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' name='entry[]' value='ENTRY1' />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' name='entry[]' value='' />
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
$('table#listings > tbody:last > tr:last input').val('')
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

You should not serialise HTML to a string when you can avoid it. You want to clone the element.

Also cache the selector to the table. This means you only need to select it once.

```
function newRow(){
    var table = $('table#listings'),
        newRow = table.find('tr:first').clone();

    newRow.find(':input').val('');
    table.find('> tbody:last').append(newRow);
}
```

Comment: Cleaner than mine.  You'ld need to drop the 'row' class selector though.

Comment: @John Thanks, didn't notice that. Will fix :)

Answer (score 0):

You had some problems in your selectors... and then what you were doing with your selectors.  : )

```
function newRow(){
   var sourceRow = $('table#listings tr').html();
   var destRow = $('<tr>'+sourceRow+'</tr>');
   destRow.find('input').val('');
   $('table#listings > tbody:last').append(destRow);
   return false;
}
```

I've made it a bit more atomic so that it is easier to read.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AguYT/3/)

---

Added:  note that there is nothing with a class of 'row' in your example.